# Select and replace a string from an xml file in all occurences via shell scripting

Tags: xml, shell

I need to replace a string in a xml file in all occurences using shell scripting

```js
<field>
               <name>CC</name>
               <displayType>USER</displayType>
               <displaySize>25</displaySize>
               <displayLines>1</displayLines>
 </field>
```

I need to replace `<name>CC</name>` in all occurences in the xml file with `<name>Carbon Copy</name>`

Comment: `xsltproc` is the tool you are looking for

Comment: @Kent is it possible that instead of writing many lines of code, i could replace the occurence in a single line ? and it should replace and save in the same file. No need to save the xml in a new file

Comment: it is possible, e.g. using sed. however, regex is always the last choice for xml. It is vulnerable...  If you are sure `<name>CC</name>` will always come in this format, I can post a sed answer. But if the format could be changed, the `sed` could be a `sad` one.

Comment: @Kent yes the string would appear always the same way

i already tried sed this way "sed -i "s~<name>Carbon Copy</name>~<name>CC</name>~g"" but i am not sure if this is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed is not a good tool to handle xml. However since you are sure the format will be kept same. (see comments under Questions), you can try with this sed line:

```
sed -i 's#<name>CC</name>#<name>Carbon Copy</name>#g' file
```

Comment: thanks this works smoothly. 
one more query, if i have more .xml files, some might have <name>Carbon Copy</name> already in place. Can you give me if case logic that whenever sed/awk reads the file <name>CC</name> then only it should run the command else it should skip the step\

Comment: you just apply the sed on all xmls, if there is no `CC`, nothing will be changed